# Adjust date to lowest value in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter

I have the following data in Table X in Microsoft SQL Server:

```
Date       Description
01.12.2010 A
02.12.2010 A
02.12.2010 A
22.03.2011 B
23.03.2011 B
23.03.2011 B
24.06.2011 C
24.06.2011 C
24.06.2011 C
28.09.2012 D
```

I would like to create a new column called "adjustedDates" where all rows with same unique description gets the earliest date of those descriptions. So for A I want all As to have the date 01.12.2010.

I am not sure how to write the query:

```
ALTER TABLE [X] ADD AdjustedDates AS (case when [description] in ("some logic") then ("some logic") else end;
```

Comment: Can the descriptions repeat?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The sample data already show they repeat.

Comment: It is Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17.

Comment: Hi, no the description is the identical only following each other, not later down the column. So "A" will not show up later than shown above.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use updatable CTEs and window functions:

```
alter table x add AdjustedDate Date;

with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
              min(date) over (partition by description) as new_adjusteddate
      from x
     )
update toupdate
    set adjusteddate = new_adjusteddate;
```

You really cannot do this with a single `alter table` command.  Well, actually you could -- if you defined a function to calculate the adjusted date.  But it is simple enough to use `update`.

Comment: Thanks! I believe this should work, but I did add in ORDER BY description, just in case. I do get an error message: ORDER BY list of RANGE window frame has total size of 2000 bytes. Largest size supported is 900 bytes....maybe too much data as there are over 150 million rows?

Comment: @KevinGarnettMVP . . . You would only use `order by` in the window function if you wanted a *cumulative* maximum.  That would be redundant with `min()`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider use of Indexed Views:

```
    CREATE VIEW [NewViewName]
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
    AS
        SELECT [Date], [Description], FIRST_VALUE([date]) OVER(PARTITION BY                                         
              [Description] ORDER BY date ASC) AS [AdjustedDates]
              FROM [X]
```